# What are the early sources of combinatorics in Hindu scripture?

Tags: vedas, mathematics

My understanding is that some of the earliest references to applied combinatorics come from Vedic sources, for instance the Ayurvedic medical treatises of Charaka and Sushruta.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, Hindu scripture does contain combinatorics.**. Here is what N.L. Biggs says in this excerpt from his journal paper "The Roots of Combinatorics":

> It seems that, from a very early time, the Hindus became accustomed to considering questions involving permutations and combinations. A typical example occurs in the medical treatise of Susruta... In chapter LXIII ... We find a discussion of the various kinds of taste which can be made by combining six basic qualities: sweet, acid, saline, pungent, bitter, and astringent. There is a systematic list of combinations: six taken separately, fifteen in twos, twenty in threes, fifteen in fours, six in fives, and one taken all together.

Biggs is referring to [this chapter](https://archive.org/stream/englishtranslati03susruoft#page/392/mode/2up) of the Sushruta Samhita, an important Ayurvedic text.  And the chapter does indeed count the number of combinations obtained taking each tastes individual, combining two together, combining three together, etc.